# Django upload csv file copy to postgresql table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I am uploading a csv file in Django :

```js
$('#import-file-dialog').on('change', function(event) {
  $('#upload-files').click();
});
```

```html
<div class="" style="padding-left: 15px;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline" id="open-file-dialog">Upload Bulk</button>
  <input type="file" id="import-file-dialog" name="import_file_dialog" style="display: none;" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="upload-files" name="upload_import" style="display: none;">Upload Bulk</button>
</div>
```

Now i want to use psycopg2 copy_from for inserting csv data to Posgresql. In django model:

```
fa = StringIO(import_data.read().decode("utf-8"))
cursor.copy_from(fa , table_name, sep=',')
commit_changes()
```

csv file data is getting store with csv header name in my table. How i remove csv header so that i could store that data to table.

Thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For skipping your CSV file header and copy the data respectively, the code is pretty simple:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

with open(csv_file, 'r') as fp:
    next(f)  # Skip header
    cursor.copy_from(fp, table_name, sep=',', columns=columns)
```

**P.S.** Don't forget to pass a tale name and an ordered set of columns, that should exactly being matched to CSV file columns ordering

Answer (score 2):

You are doing double-processing of the CSV file. `csv.reader` reads the file line-by-line and parses it into lists of fields. `copy_from` reads a file or other object and parses into fields (default to tab, but with `sep=','`  it is effectively CSV). You can either:

a) read the file directly (i.e., just open it normally instead of using `csv`) and then use `copy_from`
or
b) use csv.reader to parse and then build queries to insert each row.

The first option is much simpler. But keep in mind (from the [cursor class docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html)) that there is an optional `columns` parameter. If you don't use it then *The length and types should match the content of the file to read. If not specified, it is assumed that the entire table matches the file structure.*

Unfortunately, there is no "skip the header line" option for `copy_from`. If you need to do that, you can either (if it is a one-time load) delete the line manually, or you can use `copy_export` - something like:

`cursor.copy_expert(sql="COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS ','" % table_name, file=fa)`

Full example at [Load a CSV File with Header in Postgres via Psycopg](https://www.laurivan.com/load-a-csv-file-with-header-in-postgres-via-psycopg/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I update the question according to your suggestion but unable to remove header of csv file.

Comment: Let me try and will let you know, again thanks for answer.